# Laravel - Display data from multiple tables in one page

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have 3 tables in my database. I want to display all 3 table data on a single page.

**Student.php**

```
public function hobbies() {
    return $this->hasMany(Student::class);
}
```

**Hobbie.php**

```
public function student()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Student::class);
}
```

**Controller.php**

```
$students->name= request('name');
    $students->address = request('address');
    if($students->save())

for ($i=0; $i < count(request('hob')); ++$i) 
        {
        $hobbies = new Hobby;
        $hobbies->name= request('hob')[$i];
        $students->hobbies()->save($hobbies);
        }
```

**View.blade.php**
    $students->hobbies()->hob;

But it does not show any hobby. What is the proper solution?

Comment: what does `request('name')` do ?

Comment: Which version of laravel are you using?

Comment: What exactly you want please describe more, for e.g you want student data with hobbies ?

Comment: @RusbenGuzman 5.5

Comment: @user2486 `request('name')` sets the value of Student's name from form to database.

Comment: @NileshsinhRathod Yes! I want to display Student's name, address as well as hobbies which are saved in different table.

Comment: @universal : share complete function name of controller ?

Comment: Bunch of issues; `$students`, as a variable name, suggests a `Collection` of `Student.php (Model)`, so `$students->hobbies` would be invalid. `$student->hobbies()` would be ok. If you wanted to access a property of a single `Hobby`, (note the spelling here, not `Hobbie`), you'd do `$student->hobbies->first()->property` (No database query), or `$student->hobbies()->first()->property` (Extra database query). You need to know when you're accessing a `Collection` or a `Model`, as you'll run into a lot of issues otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your entire controller code would be helpful.

In your view `$students->hobbies()->hob;` you are accessing the property `hob` of the Collection  `$students->hobbies()`. You want to access the property `hob` of an element of the Collection `$students->hobbies()` so you probably want to access `$students->hobbies()[0]->hob` or loop through the Collection with a foreach.

Accessing `$students->hobbies()` in your view actually queries your database, so you would be better off setting a `$hobbies` variable in your controller and passing that to the view, then looking through your variable.

`@foreach ($hobbies as $hobby)
  {{ $hobby->hob }}<br/>
@endforeach`